# Use router to push Wake-On-LAN magic packet

Tags: router, wake-on-lan

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system that I can start inside my network with another Ubuntu 14.04 computer with the following command:

```
wakeonlan ma:ca:dd:re:ss

Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with ma:ca:dd:re:ss
```

However my problem is setting up the router correctly.
My firewall table says UDP statements into ports 7 and 9 are forwarded to the internal target address, but the following fails:

```
wakeonlan -i pub.lic.ipa.ddr ma:ca:dd:re:ss

Sending magic packet to pub.lic.ipa.ddr:9 with ma:ca:dd:re:ss
```

I have run an nmap command following command to test the public side ports:

```
sudo nmap -sU -p 7,9 pub.lic.ipa.ddr

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-02 01:04 AEDT
Nmap scan report for hostname (pub.lic.ipa.ddr)
Host is up (0.0034s latency).
PORT  STATE         SERVICE
7/udp open|filtered echo
9/udp open|filtered discard

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.32 seconds
```

Which looks good to me but no dice - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the router to forward the packet to the right place. This requires a static ARP entry, mapping the MAC address to the IP. It also requires a port forwarding entry to the static IP. This is pretty tricky to get right and perhaps a better idea is to arrange a way to command another machine on the LAN to send the packet.

Comment: I suspect your answer is correct, but in then end what I did was port forward my router to my "always on" raspberrypi and got it to send the magic packet. :)